# Need my app to connect with my device BLE

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I working with CC2640 and my custom APP. I have a problem that I haven't been able to solve for a couple of days. In practice, I do not risk connecting my BLE device to the APP when I use the paired. In practice, at the first connection after entering the passkey, it tells me it is connected but does not work and then the second connection no longer reads the "CONNECTED" logs. Can someone help me? This is what I wrote

```
MainActivity

@Override
                        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {  ///here??
                            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);

                            String intentAction;
                            BluetoothAdapter bleAdapter = ((BluetoothManager) getSystemService(BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter();
                            Set<BluetoothDevice> paired = bleAdapter.getBondedDevices();
                            for (BluetoothDevice device : paired) {
                                if (device.getName().equals("RCQ4-BLE")) {
                                    Log.i("Paired", "It paired" + bleAdapter.getBondedDevices());
                                    if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
                                        intentAction = ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED;
                                        Log.i("gattCallBack", "STATE CONNECTED");
                                        broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server");
                                        Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:" + gatt.discoverServices());
                                    } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                                        intentAction = ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED;
                                        Log.i("gattCallBack", "STATE DISCONNECTED");
                                        broadcastUpdate(intentAction);
                                    } else if (mBluetoothGatt != null) {
                                        mBluetoothGatt.disconnect();
                                        mBluetoothGatt = null;
                                    } else {
                                        Log.w(TAG, "onConnectionStateChange() status = " + status + "newState = " + newState);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }

Selected Device

private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver4 = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_BOND_STATE, -1);
        int prevstate = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_BOND_STATE, -1);

        String msg = "Bond state change: state" + pairstate(state) + "previous state" + pairstate(prevstate);
        Log.w("Bond state receiver", msg);
    }

    private String pairstate(int state) {
            switch (state) {
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDING: Log.i("Bond status:", "Bonding..");

                    //device.createBond();
                    // onBondingRequired();
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_BONDED:
                    Log.i("Bond status:", "Bonded");
                    //  onBonded();
                    break;
                case BluetoothDevice.BOND_NONE:
                    Log.i("Bond status:", "Fail");
                    // onBondingFailed();
                default:
                    return String.valueOf(state);

            }
            return(null);
       }
};

private final BroadcastReceiver mGattUpdateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        final String action = intent.getAction();
            switch(action)
            {
        case MainActivity.ACTION_GATT_CONNECTED:
            // updateConnectionState(R.string.connected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            break;
        case MainActivity.ACTION_GATT_DISCONNECTED:
            // updateConnectionState(R.string.disconnected);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
            clearUI();
            break;
        case MainActivity.ACTION_GATT_SERVICES_DISCOVERED:
            initializeGattServiceUIElements(mMainActivity.getSupportedGattServices());
            break;
```

Comment: Did you check that there are no Characteristics you have to enable to keep the connection? I've once had the problem that I only waited for the on Connection state changed but without enabling the services and characteristics my connection fails after few seconds

Comment: Did you perform a service discovery?

Comment: Yes, I have a service discovery. But nothing. Because when I use the my app, without the paired it works very well

Comment: Do you also use classic. Bluetooth in parallel? Note that Android would also return devices which are only EDR paired but.not BLE bonded.